Need help controlling a 2d rocket to reach target positions at velocity vector constraints
The problem:
I have a rocket in a 2D space game that can apply force forwards and apply torque to turn. Now I want this rocket to reach a target point in the x,y coordinate system with a certain velocity vector.
This target point at this velocity vector should be reached as fast as possible given some max force and max torque values.
Essentially, given initial start state vectors: start_position, start_rotation and start_velocity. Reach final end state vectors: end_position and end_velocity. With forward force and torque being our only methods of achieving this.
Edit: Common rigidbody2d properties can still be read every frame though, such as position, rotation, mass, inertia, velocity and angular velocity.
The (almost) simplest case would be starting at the (0,0) position with (1,0) start_rotation and having to reach a target point straight ahead with end_velocity vector being a scalar of the current rotation.
Say reach position (10,0) with velocity vector (_,0). Forward force would just need to be applied until (10,0) is reached.
Given the same starting conditions and target position but the target velocity vector being the 0 vector is quite a bit more complex. It would involve first accelerating then turning 180 degrees then accelerating in the opposite direction in order to perfectly stop at (10,0).
In the previous example a further complication might be that the initial velocity is say (0,2) then the traveled line would also be curvy in order to counteract the initial velocity and end up at the final state with (0,0) velocity.
In the end this controller should be able to reach (within some error) any ending state from any starting state.
Now designing a controller seems quite difficult. So I was wondering what strategies the good people here might suggest.

Some sort of control theory approach? I'm not super familiar here especially given the multiple requirements. I don't even see how something like a PID-controller would work, what would the error-signal even be?

A machine learning approach perhaps?

Something I haven't even heard of?



I've written some guided missile code in 2d before. It's pretty tricky. The part of your question that gives me pause is "as fast as possible". That strikes me as a potentially very difficult problem to solve. Already trying to guarantee a specific velocity vector seems difficult. I know this isn't super helpful; it's just some of my thoughts on the problem having worked on this kind of thing before.

I have similar concerns as Almo. Does your use case in your game leave any room to approximate this? We can get some easy-to-compute closed-form solutions if we relax the constraints a little. In most games, it would be difficult for a player to judge whether a missile trajectory was truly the mathematically perfect optimal path versus just "physically plausible and reasonably direct". In some cases we might even want to depart from that if it enhances the "cool factor" or supports balancing considerations. Can you give us more context on your needs, and which of these criteria are must-have?

Well the point of this is to move from one point to another and be able to continue to move from there wherever it is we want to go. This should be done far faster than essentially doing sequential tasks preferably. I suppose I could simplify the problem by only every needing to stop at the end position and lets say be at least 80% or so of as fast as possible. Though even finding out what is the fastest way is still part of the problem.

If you just want a way to get from point A with velocity vA to point B with velocity vB, you can use the cubic Bézier trick shown in this answer. This simplifies your rocket from one with torque and thrust to one with a linearly varying acceleration vector, and you can adjust the time gap between A & B to obey max acceleration constraints. This lets you directly calculate the curve from your A/vA/B/vB information, and should look physically plausible enough on screen, especially for a fast-moving rocket.

I really do want to include torque and angular velocity though and not just apply thrust in any direction. I might explore some machine learning solution instead.
